# Springboot project jar not run give exception in unix enviorment

Tags: java, spring

Develop standalone application with spring Boot and maven used for building application.I am trying to move this jar file to different unix environment and trying to deploy it.While trying to execute I am getting below error

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-01-10
>   10:16:27.345 ERROR 13211 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication :
>   Application startup failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)

Comment: There are a few ways to run springboot application. You need to share how to run your application to get correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Run project using 
java - jar pathtojarfile/nameofjarfile.jar

If project still not run then it could be problem related jre please check jre version and it's archetype.